# creating a html mailto with php

Tags: php, html

cannot use the mail function in php, will be creating a mailto link in html instead. (the kind you click on and it pops up a window)

I have the body of the message saved under a variable $body and the email address saved under $email

```
<?php

echo"
<a href="mailto: $to  ?body= $body ">
";

?>
```

I know that code would not work, how do I put the email address and the body variables in there? thanks

Comment: to want to send a mail through PHP or just want to ouput a A tag with mailto?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`echo "<a href='mailto:" . $to . "?body=" . $body . "'>";`

Answer (score 6):

```
$fixed_body = htmlspecialchars($body);
echo <<<EOL
<a href="mailto:$email?body=$fixed_body">Click here</a>
EOL;
```

htmlspecialchars will prevent any `"` in the email body from "breaking" the `<a>` tag. And the heredoc is just a nice little touch so you can use direct variable interpolation without having to escape the href attribute quotes.

Answer (score 4):

Try with this:

```
<a href="mailto:<?php echo $to; ?>?body=<?php echo $body; ?>"><?php echo $to; ?></a>
```

Will generate

```
<a href="mailto:youremail@mail.com?body=This is the body of the message">youremail@mail.com</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is (I've put spaces all over php tags for this editor to take all my characters and not interpret them):

```
< a href="mailto:< ? php echo $to; ? >?subject=< ? php echo $subject; ? >&cc=< ? php echo $cc; ? >&body=< ? php echo $body;? > " >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href='mailto:'<?php echo $to ?>'><?php echo $body ?></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php

echo "<a href='mailto:{$to}?body={$body}'>";

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Basically you want something that looks like this:

`<a href="mailto:$to?subject=$subject&body=$body&cc=$cc">`